# Issue reading pickle file created from higher version but need to use in lower version

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I created pickle file using version pandas  0.22.2 py 3.6 but when im trying to use in pandas 0.18.1 version ca't able to load follwing error ,
mportError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes'

even i tried using pd.read_pickle

please help on this issue

Comment: You could use pandas 0.18.1 to read the data and then write it to a file that is not a pickle, e.g. a CSV. CSV files can be parsed with any pandas version.

Comment: actually in pickle i have classification model stored

Comment: Pickle is a bad data storage format for this and other reasons.

Comment: pandas does not provide classification models. You might be trying to load a pickle file with pandas that was not generated with pandas. It is nearly impossible to help you without knowing exactly how the pickle file was created. If you can, just get the data and parameters with which the classifier was trained and train it again.

Comment: If the model is a scikit-learn model you bight find relevant information here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is not a good choice in this case as it depends on the ability to import the class definition of what was pickled. You'd better try with JSON instead using [data frame to JSON](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and [read JSON](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.read_json.html). The docs show this is quite straightforward.